# Populating Bash array fails

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop

Here is a simple command I am running in bash, but the array won;t get populated for some reason.

```
array=() && sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address'| while read line; do array[${#array[@]}]=$line; done
```

I have also tried to populate the array this way:

```
array=()
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address'| while read line; do array+=($line); done
```

but it gives me the same result. I know it works because when i do this:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address'| while read line; do "echo $line"; done
```

it will print every line that is piped from grep to the while loop.

When I check the size of the array " echo ${#array[@] " it will show 0 and if I print the array it obviously prints nothing. Do you see any errors in the line?

**UPDATE. I got it working by using a for loop like so:

```
for line in $(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address' -A5); do array+=($line); done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BASH FAQ entry #24: ["I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)

> The while loop [...] is executed in a new subshell with its own copy of the variable [...]

Use the following as a workaround:

```
while read line;
    do array+=("$line")
done < <(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address')
```

Comment: Even thought I have used bash for a long time, I did not know that since I always used while read to print data directly without having to store it anywhere. Anyway, I solved my problem by using a for loop like so : for line in (sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address');do  array+=($line); done. Cheers

Comment: @JuanCarlos Using a `for` loop is not a good idea since the expanded values in `$()` would be open for pathname expansion and would give you different values for `$line` sometimes. It also makes bash allocate a large buffer for the whole output first before reading each lines which is not a good thing for large outputs compared to reading with `while`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use process substitution instead:

```
array=()
while read line; do array+=($line); done < <(exec sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address')
```

Or use lastpipe option:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
array=() && sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address'| while read line; do array[${#array[@]}]=$line; done
```

It's also cheaper to use `readarray` or `mapfile` if you're using Bash 4.0+. No need to initialize `array` with `()` and is only needed to be redeclared if it was previously declared to a different type in a more global context.

```
readarray -t array < <(exec sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address')

shopt -s lastpipe
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep 'Address' | readarray -t array
```